# problem with WFS Data, GDAL, Python, ArcGIS, & Defining Projection

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, gdal, wfs, ogr2ogr

I'm pulling in data in gml2 format with a EPSG#4267 from a wfs.

I create a datastream in python and then run the following from the python window in ArcMap:

```
data = datastream.read()

#write the gml data to a gml file
rasterdata = open("E:\\Melo\\USGS" + "\\Roads.gml", 'w')
rasterdata.write(data)
rasterdata.close()

#Run the ogr2ogr to convert to shp
cmd = ["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "E:\\Roads.shp", "E:\\Roads.gml"]
subprocess.call(cmd)

#Define the projection
infc ="E:\\Roads.shp"
prjfile = "E:\\4267.prj"
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(infc, prjfile)
```

Unfortunately, when i try to add the layer in ArcMap 10.1 it "appears" blank.  Typically, I've only seen this happen when their was something wrong with the projection.  I know there is data in the file because I've converted it successfully using alternate methods.

I installd GDAL according to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009506/unable-to-install-python-and-gdal-dll-load-failed) instructions exactly (1500/32 bit/2.7).

I did NOT download and install the [ArcGIS bindings](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1eec30bf5fa042a5a2227b094db89441).  Do I need them?

Any ideas on what could be causing the layer to appear blank in ArcMap?

Comment: Are there any features in the Roads shapefile? What about in the attribute table? If you don't define the coordinate system or Clear the data frame's coordinate system, can you see the features?

Comment: If I start with a fresh map document ("clearing" the data frame's CS?), and bring in a copy of the shapefile WITHOUT the prj defined, I do NOT see the features.  Yes there are features in the dataset.  Whether there is a projection defined or not, I can see the attribute table (there are ~500 features & ~ 10 attribute columns).

Comment: I assume you've checked the output of ogrinfo -al -so on Roads.gml and the resulting Roads.shp? Have you tried running ogr2ogr directly on the command-line, i.e. outside of your python script?

Comment: Why not convert the [WFS directly](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_wfs.html)? `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" E:\\Roads.shp WFS:http://path/to/WFS/service`

Comment: @dmci: When I run ogrinfo on the gml file, I get <a href="http://smallmelo.com/ogrinfo_gml.PNG">this</a> and when I run it on the shp file I get <a href="http://smallmelo.com/ogrinfo_shp.PNG">this</a>.  When I run ogr2ogr directly from command line, I get the same results.

Comment: @Luke: I may be getting closer to the problem.  When I convert the WFS directly (from cmd line), it fails to read the results from the wfs.  I tried sending the request via the browser and I get an XML file back, no matter what output format I specify in the request. Is it safe to assume that I'm also getting XML back (even though I'm requesting GML) when I run the script. Could my problem be that I'm unintentionally saving an xml result with a gml extension and then trying to convert THAT into a shp file?

Comment: Another detail to add, is that prior to installing gdal & its python bindings using the method mentioned above, I ran the same ogr2ogr command using FWTools and it created the shp file fine.  I uninstalled FWTools because I ONLY wanted gdal & I wanted to run it via python (I've since learned that I can use the command line via python).  Before I make anymore software changes, I wanted to reach out for help.